# Torch Ubuntu install.deps : Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, torch

Im trying to install torch on ubuntu environment. I had the problem with `python-software-properties` that I solved by changing in script with `software-properties-common`. I had another trouble with libQT4-dev package, which I think I fixed following this thread : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426132/e-unable-to-locate-package-libqt4-dev-while-trying-to-install-torch-ubuntu-2

But now I got this error due to ipython package. I followed everything I founded on the subject nothing works. In my conda env, i got ipython install

[image: ipython error when i run install.deps, with conda list proof]

I tried to install ipython using pip, using apt, and conda. Nothing seems to work

Any suggestion ?

EDIT :

I can also run the ipython command and it is working. Which means that environmenet variable are all set, there is no problem from this side

Answer (score 2):

For me changing `ipython` to `ipython3` in `install-deps` solved the problem.

Comment: Well also tried it, did not work !

Comment: This worked for me. (I ran `sed -i 's/ipython/ipython3/g' install-deps` to replace all occurrences.)